# How to fill TextBox inside ItemsRepeater in WinUI 3?

Tags: layout, .net-6.0, winui-3

I'm trying to fill all the width space with a list of TextBox inside a collection. In UWP was so simple as adding `<UniformGrid Rows="1"/> to ItemsControl`, but using WinUI 3 I need to change to `ItemsRepeater and UniformGridLayout` but there's no Row property in UniformGridLayout. This is my code:

```
<ItemsRepeater ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Specimens}">
    <ItemsRepeater.Layout>
        <UniformGridLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemsStretch="Fill"/>
    </ItemsRepeater.Layout>
    <ItemsRepeater.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:SpecimenViewModel">
            <TextBox Margin="10" Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsRepeater.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsRepeater>
```

This is what is showing:
[image]

Expected behaviour:
[image]

Finally, I could check that the TextBox increase their sizes at same time as the text inside increase, but I want to have the same width all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were nearly there I think you just needed to add the MaximumRowsOrColumns to the number of columns, put some space around with MinColumnSpacing="10" ItemsJustification="SpaceAround"

for example something like:

```
<UniformGridLayout MinColumnSpacing="10"
                            ItemsJustification="SpaceAround" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" Orientation="Horizontal" ItemsStretch="Uniform"/>
```

**edit**: I Changed ItemsStretch Fill to Uniform, it's a better experience when have different height content

Comment: MaximumRowsOrColumns did the Trick.

<UniformGridLayout 
    Orientation="Horizontal" 
    ItemsStretch="Fill" 
    MaximumRowsOrColumns="{x:Bind ViewModel.Specimens.Count}"/>

Comment: Excellent. I like the addition of the binding.